# Formula Appliance in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

My input data is like this

```
wavelength   reflectance
341.6        1.15  
343.1        1.14
344.7        1.13
346.3        1.14
347.9        1.14
349.5        1.12
351.1        1.12
352.6        1.13
354.2        1.13
```

I am using this formula
**Query1**

```
WITH test AS(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(wavelength AS NUMERIC)-CAST (wavelength AS NUMERIC )%10 ORDER BY wavelength) AS ROW_ID,wavelength,reflectance 
  FROM test
)
SELECT wavelength,reflectance 
FROM test 
WHERE ROW_ID=1;
```

This query provides the following output

```
wavelength   reflectance
341.6        1.15
351.1        1.12
360.5        1.17
371.5        1.19
380.8        1.26
390.1        1.36
401          1.44
410.2        1.49
420.9        1.57
```

I want to change the wavelength intervals according to the query like this

```
wavelength reflectance
340        1.15
350        1.12
360        1.17
370        1.19
380        1.26
390        1.36
400        1.44
410        1.49
420        1.57
```

**Query2:**

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
    PARTITION BY CAST(wavelength AS INT)
                 -CAST(wavelength AS INT)%20
    ORDER BY wavelength) AS ROW_ID,
  wavelength,
  avg( reflectance ) OVER(
    PARTITION BY CAST(wavelength AS INT)
                 -CAST(wavelength AS INT)%20
    ORDER BY wavelength
    rows BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING
         and UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) As reflectance 
  FROM 
  abi
)
select wavelength, reflectance
from CTE
where row_id = 1
```

This Query Provides the following output

```
wavelength    reflectance
341.6         1.13636363636364
360.5         1.19666666666667
380.8         1.35833333333333
401;1         49916666666667
420.9         1.685
440.8         1.95083333333333
460.5         2.16666666666667
```

I want the output like this

```
wavelength    reflectance
340           1.13636363636364
360           1.19666666666667
380           1.35833333333333
400           49916666666667
420           1.685
440           1.95083333333333
460           2.16666666666667
```

i'm trying according to this in Postgresql, but it shows error, anyone help me if it is possible in PostgreSQL or i will use any other things suggest me..

Comment: "*but it shows error*" - and the error is?

Comment: What about using `trunc`function ?

Comment: i tried this in 2nd query, The error isERROR:  syntax error at or near "OVER"
LINE 8:   wavelength OVER(
                     ^
********** Error **********
ERROR: syntax error at or near "OVER"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 179

Comment: i dont know about trunc function, what is that? how i use in this query...

Comment: @AbishekArumugamR Your Query1 does not provide the data that you have posted: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c9e52/1

Comment: @Houari My data consists of 2 columns and 2500 rows, some rows are not put in input data, According to ur tips mine is working now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tips using [trunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html) function:

```
select trunc(341.6/10) *10
```

output:

```
340
```